# Print Webpage as Displayed in Browser

Tags: html, css, printing

I currently have a webpage that displays an application.  The purpose of this was so that a user would be able to receive a version of this application pre-filled with their information so they would be able to print it out.  Currently the page looks great and matches the application almost one for one.

UNFORTUNATELY when looking at the print preview it is a horrific mess; there are line breaks everywhere and nothing seems to line up the way it looks when looking at the webpage.

Is there something I have to do to have the CSS rules applied to the printed version of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHELP, I found when I added "print" to media, it applied the CSS correctly and now is displaying as it should.

So this basically fixed the issue...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css" media="screen, print">
```

[image: Crisis: Averted.]

Comment: Yeah, was about to suggest that. For more info checkout: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: I would recommend `media="all"`, unless you have a separate stylesheet for something else, like `tv`.